# Calculate sum of true/false checkbox cells

Tags: ipad, numbers

I can add true/false buttons ok. I wish to have these buttons equal a number when it's ticked then be added to a total.

I'm brand new to numbers but finding my way ok so far. I do team sheets. Each member pays £2 I wish to just use a tick box to confirm they have paid then total what the true buttons.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

To calculate the sum of the checkboxes, where checked is 1 and unchecked is 0, use:

```
=COUNTIF(A, true)
```

Replace A with the range of cells where the checkboxes are.

[image]

You can combine this with ×2 to multiply the answer by 2, then format as currency.

[image]

Comment: I am almost getting there. do I have to the formula again for rack checkbox?

Comment: @The I'm don't understand your question, the formula is input once into the cell. What's a ‘rack checkbox’?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. I should have checked text correctly. I can type first line of formula and It works. True checkbox = 2. I am now trying to repeat for all checkboxes. So trying to work that out just now.

Comment: @The Why are you repeating the formula for each checkbox? The first parameter to countif takes a *range* of checkboxes and sums the checked cells.

Comment: Ok! New day! New learning. Thankyou firstly for your help. I Have managed now. Thankyou again